# About "2 accept or reject votes are required to approve/reject an edit" on Stack Overflow

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits

I noticed that the rule of approving suggested edits on Stack Overflow is "2 accept or reject votes are required to approve/reject an edit" ([the last paragraph of an answer to *How do suggested edits work?*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76251/how-does-peer-review-for-edits-work/76284#76284)).

But according to my experience on Stack Overflow, it just need one vote. If someone edits one of my questions or answers, it will be approved after I approve or reject it, just one vote from me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think, you are right that your vote alone is enough if you are owner of the post.

https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/25126
https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/58539
https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/80097

Comment: If you (with 2000+ rep) approve a suggest edit, and choose Improve function to improve it, then your version also need approve? it means Stackoverflow will damage the users' privilege of direct edit who have with 2000+ rep.

Comment: @Roy, No, Community user will approve it first, before my new edit for that case.

Comment: thank you for your answer.You solved part of my question. But I still have a query: is your version from improving the pending version must be apprved?

Comment: @Roy, Oops! I wanted to say that, it will be normal edit to 2000+ user, once Community user approved existing pending edit. So, no approvment needed.